# setInterval function cannot get updated now value

Tags: javascript

evaluateSlider function is being called on each step while slider is sliding.
In the first call,  setInterval function is initiated to track the time difference between current time and the last slide step.
setTimeInterval function can get only the first value on "getNow()" and all other slider steps are ignored.

How can I get updated "getNow" into setInterval function.

```
    var sliderFirstStart = true;

    var evaluateSlider = function (e) {

        var now = (new Date()).getTime();
        var getNow = function () {
            return now;
        };

        if (sliderFirstStart) {
            setInterval(function () {

                console.log('time diff tracker > ', (new Date()).getTime(), getNow(), (new Date()).getTime() - getNow())
            }, 1000);
        }

        sliderFirstStart = false;

    }
```

**EDIT**
This is working version but how about that? I dont get it why not working inside evaluateSlider function.

```
var now;
var getNow = function () {
        return now;
};

var sliderFirstStart = true;

var evaluateSlider = function (e) {

now = (new Date()).getTime();

if (sliderFirstStart) {
setInterval(function () {

console.log('time diff tracker > ', (new Date()).getTime(), getNow(), (new Date()).getTime() - getNow())
}, 1000);
}

sliderFirstStart = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem. Adding a `evaluateSlider()` after all of this code, in order to call it and test it, it worked fine. I get the times and time difference logged into the console each second for every call.

Comment: I edited my code and it is working now. But I cannot get it why this is working.

Comment: do you call evaluateSlider more then once? where is the clearInterval. and in the interval you do not update the var now.. and getNow function return the var now.. so.. ?

Answer (score 0):

place your `var now` inside the `getNow` function to return a new time every time its getting called.

```
    var getNow = function () {
        var now = (new Date()).getTime(); 
        return now;
    };
```

Comment: This is not working, but thanks for your intention.

Comment: interesting, the change now its working because you are referencing now outside of your function which is returning new value...